# amqp_login giving "Argument list too long" error?

Tags: c, messaging, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using c library of RabbitMQ. It has a function amqp_login

I am using it as following.

```
 ::amqp_rpc_reply_t c_amqp_rpc_reply = 
                       ::amqp_login
                             ( m_amqp_connection_state
                             , "fortytwo"
                             , 0
                             , FRAME_MAX
                             , 0
                             , 131072
                             , "guest"
                             , "guest"
                             );
```

Its giving me error as Argument list too long.

Any one have any idea to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It would really help to know the version of librabbitmq you're using.

The current version has this prototype for `amqp_login`, so your sixth parameter (131072) looks suspicious.

```
RABBITMQ_EXPORT amqp_rpc_reply_t amqp_login(amqp_connection_state_t state,
                                            char const *vhost,
                                            int channel_max,
                                            int frame_max,
                                            int heartbeat,
                                            amqp_sasl_method_enum sasl_method, ...);
```

Looking at the examples, I guess you probably want:

```
amqp_login(conn, "/", 0, 131072, 0,
           AMQP_SASL_METHOD_PLAIN,
           "guest", "guest");
```

You could also try the new fangled [AMQP URI](http://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html) [parser](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-c/file/default/librabbitmq/amqp_url.c).  Again, look at the examples to see how it's used.